# How to forecast timeseries based on different events?

Tags: neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I have a few IoT sensors around my house that over time store some events with timestamps. Each sensor has a unique type e.g. ‘front’ or ‘back’. Let’s call this set X.

Now I have one sensor which value is dependent on X. I have a value for approximately every 5 minutes over the last year. Let’s call this set Y.

Now my goal is to create a model that given a current point and and a few hours of history (X events have influence on Y for longer time), it gives me the forecast of Y for the next 3 hours.

How would one go and create such a model? Any common architectures for such inputs and outputs? I’d like to setup a neural network to allow to find patterns between different IoT sensors.

Comment: Are the events categorical, or do they have numerical values associated with them? I take it Y is numerical?

Comment: When you say "each sensor has unique a type", do you mean that each sensor has distinct event types? Do you have multiple sensor of the same kind?

Comment: What you should start with is to compute some statistics on X and Y to start to understand how they are related. Once you start to get an idea for that, building a model for it is often rather easy